# Switch from rigged character to ragdoll

Tags: animation, rigging, physics

I am planning an animation in which I have one or more rigged robots following some Motion Capture (MoCap) data simultaneously.
Once they have finished following the MoCap sequence, I want them to collapse to the floor in RagDoll fashion.

I know about rigging the robots and making them follow the MoCap data stored in a .bvh file.  My question is, how do I turn them into ragdolls?
Obviously, I want all their parts to stay connected together, so I guess they will still require an armature, but to have no muscular strength to hold them upright, so that they fall in a heap under the influence of gravity.